Maintain different Angular Versions in one pnpm Workspace
Currently, I am working on a demo, setting up a Micro Frontend Environment with Angular 16 and Angular 17 apps.
I am trying to set these apps up in one workspace: https://github.com/GregOnNet/ng-microfrontend
I use the following settings in my .npmrc to keep the applications as separate as possible to avoid conflicts between packages. (If I do not do so, Angular CLI version 17 is resolved in an Angular version 16 project.)
shared-workspace-lockfile = false
hoist = false
hoist-workspace-packages = false

Now, I am experiencing another error: TypeScript cannot be resolved.
✘ [ERROR] Cannot find package '~\ng-microfrontend\packages\remote-ng-16\node_modules\.pnpm\@angular+com…
│ Did you mean to import typescript@5.1.3/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js? [plugin angular-compiler]


Questions
How can I set up a functioning workspace containing different versions of the same package?
Do I misunderstand the concept of a pnpm workspace?
